# Rails 3.2 Trying to Reduce Repetition in jQuery Ajax Remote Forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1, coffeescript

I have developed a back-end in Rails 3.2 that allows admins to perform CRUD operations using ajax and jQuery.  I have done this with several controller/views using js.coffee files to handle the ajax. an example of my file structure for my views is as follows.

```
views
  users
    index.html.erb
    _form.html.erb
    _edit_form.html.erb
    _user.html.erb
    create.js.coffee
    edit.js.coffee        
    update.js.coffee
    destroy.js.coffee
  customers
    index.html.erb
    _form.html.erb
    _edit_form.html.erb
    _customer.html.erb
    create.js.coffee
    edit.js.coffee        
    update.js.coffee
    destroy.js.coffee
   email_blasts
     index.html.erb
     _form.html.erb
     _edit_form.html.erb
     _blast.html.erb
     create.js.coffee
     edit.js.coffee        
     update.js.coffee
     destroy.js.coffee
  .
  .
  .
  .
```

An example create.js.coffee for both the User views and Customer views is below.  Notice the instance variables and div names that follow an exact pattern.  All coffeescript below follows the exact structure in all the views that I have listed above.  All create.js.coffee files listed above are virtually identical.  My question is what's the best way to reduce the duplication?  Would this be something that I should create a plugin for?  Should I put it in a helper...etc.  I'm not sure how to handle this in rails as I am a former php programmer :(  Anyones help would be appreciated!

create.js.coffee for the User views:

```
$('#errors').empty()
$('#errors').show()
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
  $('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "errors", :locals => {:target => @user })%>')
    .appendTo('#errors')
<% else %>
  $('<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @user))%>')
    .appendTo('#user_table')
    .hide()
    .fadeIn(200)
$('#errors').hide()
$('#new_user')[0].reset()
$('#users_count').html '<%= users_count %>'
<% end %>
$('#error_close').click ->
  $('#errors').fadeOut()
```

create.js.coffee for the Customer view

```
$('#errors').empty()
$('#errors').show()
<% if @customer.errors.any? %>
  $('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "errors", :locals => {:target => @customer })%>')
    .appendTo('#errors')
<% else %>
  $('<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @customer))%>')
    .appendTo('#customer_table')
    .hide()
    .fadeIn(200)
  $('#errors').hide()
  $('#new_customer')[0].reset()
  $('#customers_count').html '<%= customers_count %>'
<% end %>
$('#error_close').click ->
  $('#errors').fadeOut()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should structure your code and if you want to reuse it stop mixing javascript and erb.  Make JavaScript classes which do the job and put the data in side a script tag in the page...

Try to use some framework which helps you by giving structure like Backbone.js.

This could be useful to you:

- http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/
- http://backbonetutorials.com/
- http://ricostacruz.com/backbone-patterns/

Or the messy way:

```
# Function 
foo = (condition, firstBlock, secondBlock) ->
  $('#errors').empty()
  $('#errors').show()
  if condition
    firstBlock
      .appendTo('#errors')
  else
    secondBlock
      .appendTo('#customer_table')
      .hide()
      .fadeIn(200)
    $('#errors').hide()
    $('#new_customer')[0].reset()
    $('#customers_count').html '<%= customers_count %>'
  $('#error_close').click ->
    $('#errors').fadeOut()

# Execution
foo(<% @user.errors.any? %>, $('<%= stuff %>'), $('<%= moreStuff %>'))
```

Comment: If you have a RailsCasts Pro subscription you also can refer to: http://railscasts.com/episodes/323-backbone-on-rails-part-1, http://railscasts.com/episodes/325-backbone-on-rails-part-2

Comment: Why does mixing erb and javascript make reusing code harder?  Is there a way to accomplish what I need without using server-side javascript?

Comment: How do you want to reuse code which is full of preset variables for a specific situation? You can reuse generic and clean things, this code is just specific. So you need to extract the generic part and call it parametrized where you need it. So the most of the code goes in a reuseable class each page which uses it can call it with erb and all parameters.